# Is there any way to make only a portion of a graph transparent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am currently trying to make a graph using matplotlib. This is what I have so far.
[image]

I want to make the graph below 0 transparent so that the background shows through. It should look like this:
[image]

Is there anyway I can accomplish this? I'm also currently setting the background image around the border by creating a extra axis. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)` to start at 0 and `ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=10)` to make the x-ticks longer.  Your background image seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ax.fill_between with np.minimum(y, 0) to cap the y values of the black area below zero and zorder to make it go behind the blue fill below the graph line. Then interpolate=True to make it more smooth.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x - np.pi / 2)  # Shifting the phase to make the sine wave start downwards

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color='blue', zorder=3)

# Blue fill below graph
ax.fill_between(x, y, -1, color='blue', alpha=0.3, zorder=2)

# Black fill above graph below zero
ax.fill_between(x, np.minimum(y, 0), 0, where=(y < 0), interpolate=True, color='black', alpha=1, zorder=1)

plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image: graph example]

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely what you are asking for, but maybe it will give you an idea:

You could "lift the curtain" by rescaling the background rectangle of the figure:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1990, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2030]
y = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
plt.figure(facecolor="green")
plt.plot(x, y, "k")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.fill_between(x, y, interpolate=True, color="violet")

# get target scaling ratio of background rectangle
ylim_ratio = ax.get_ylim()[1] / [ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]]

#apply ratio to rectangle height and position
ax.get_children()[-1].set_height(ylim_ratio)
ax.get_children()[-1].set_y(1 - ylim_ratio)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different axes for above and below zero and set the background transparencies independently, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# some simulated data
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
data = -2 + 0.1 * x + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x * 0.5 + 0.4) + 1.0 * np.random.randn(len(x))

# get axis ratios from data for the above and below zero axes
axrange = data.max() - data.min()
topaxis = data.max() / axrange
botaxis = np.abs(data.min()) / axrange

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=2,
    sharex=True,
    height_ratios=[topaxis, botaxis],  # ratios of axis heights
    gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0},  # no space between the axes
    facecolor="black"
)

# plot the same data on both axes and limit their ranges
ax[0].fill_between(x, data, edgecolor="blue", facecolor="lightskyblue")
ax[0].set_ybound(lower=0)
ax[1].fill_between(x, data, edgecolor="blue", facecolor="lightskyblue")
ax[1].set_ybound(upper=0)
ax[1].set_xlim([x[0], x[-1]])

# set the tick colours to white
ax[0].tick_params(axis="both", direction="out", color="white")
ax[1].tick_params(axis="y", direction="out", color="white")

for s in ["top", "bottom", "left", "right"]:
    ax[0].spines[s].set_color("white")
    ax[1].spines[s].set_color("white")

ax[1].spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax[1].spines["right"].set_visible(False)

# set the transparancy of the lower axis
ax[1].patch.set_alpha(0.0)
```

This produces:

[image]